# How to remove brackets from RDD output?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

When I print an RDD I get the following result:

```
[(46, u'15910'), (43, u'15287'), (43, u'15237'), (42, u'15923'), (41, u'15298')]
```

I want to save the RDD output to a csv file without brackets or the 'u' sign, similar to below:

```
46, 15910
43, 15287
43, 15237
42, 15923
41, 15298
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either write csv:

```
>>> rdd.toDF().write.csv("path")
```

or format:

```
>>> rdd.map(lambda (k, v): "{0},{1}".format(k, v)).saveAsTextFile("path")
```